# Secha touch - Opinions on performance using large data sets

Tags: javascript, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Am currently working on a sencha touch real estate app to list properties. 
We have a data set with ~ 500  records and need to
filter a list of these records by user input based on one (maybe more than one) property.
filter the list by an exact property and then filter again by user input
group the list by a property

Currently am implemented list-Paging plugin and loading 20 records in each request. But my client feels like loading all 500 records in a single request and cache those data in local storage. It will refresh the data only when there is any change in records.

My question is is it a feasible solution to load 500 records in a single request.?
Can sencha touch can handle 500 records in its store?
Is there any performance issue by doing this?

This is my one record json

```
 {
            "id": 0,
            "ReoAddress": "*testproperty,  N,  42342, 3423, thrissur, AR, 3423432",
            "ReoId": "407",
            "AgentAssigned": "1",
            "IsViewed": "1",
            "PPView": 2,
            "RecordCount": 368,
            "items": [
                {
                    "leaf": true,
                    "ReoId": "407",
                    "ReoImageUrl": "http://192.168.3.6:92/abraham/CRM_API/GetPropertyPhoto.ashx?ReoImgPath=G9/C+sKDbWKF/OCw22r5QN2UCNW1BwGW",
                    "ClientName": "Bank of America",
                    "ListingAgentContactName": "",
                    "MLSSNumber": "10",
                    "MLSStatus": "Sold",
                    "LockboxType": "",
                    "LockboxCode": "",
                    "NumberOfBedRooms": "0",
                    "NumberOfBathRooms": "0.00",
                    "GarageSpace": "0",
                    "IntSqFt": "0",
                    "CurrentListingPrice": "",
                    "PPView": 2
                }
            ]
        }
```

Please guide me in right direction. Thank you

Comment: 500 paper clips takes up a different amount of room than 500 bricks, so it depends on your data. 500 items is likely no problem (<10kb/item), and keeping the data inches from the user instead of miles will result in a quicker experience.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks for your quick reply. I have edited my question to include my example record. Can u please comment on this.

Comment: assuming that item is typical, you can store 2000+ items in all browsers since IE8... you can easily double or triple that by using shorter key names, deflate(theJSON), or saving ordered arrays instead of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Storing the data in javascript memory is highly unlikely to be a problem at all. I store thousands of records in memory at a time in my apps - no problem.

What is a problem is if you have a store with hundreds of records which are then all in the DOM simultaneously. 500 dataview items in the DOM will cause you huge performance issues. An infinite list would get around this issue for you too.

HTML5 is all about DOM performance. The less DOM elements, the better performance. So be aware of what Sencha Touch does in the background in terms of representing stores in dataviews/lists.

You might find some further tips in a blog post I wrote about Sencha Touch's data structure : http://senchatouchdev.com/wordpress/2014/01/03/an-overview-of-sencha-touch-2s-data-system/